# Google plus link rel publisher causes crawl errors

Tags: google-plus, google-search-console

I added to my site http://www.georgia-tours.eu/ before  rel published link https://plus.google.com/b/114199965403815819875/+GeorgiatoursEuge/ to link site with google+ profile, Linking seems to work ok, but in Google webmaster tools start to appear such crowl errors 404

```
http://www.georgia-tours.eu/merabs-guesthouse-in-ambrolauri/%E2%80%9Dhttps:/plus.google.com/b/114199965403815819875/+GeorgiatoursEuge/%E2%80%9D/
```

What ideas how to fix it??

Answer (score 1):

`%E2%80%9D` decodes to `”` which is a rich quote (commonly found in Microsoft Word) and not the same as a `"` (ASCII quote). HTML Markup doesn't recognize rich quotes the same way as standard quotes and they cause issues.

Change the rich quotes to standard quotes in the source code you copied. You should also fix the Google+ URL. It should be `https://plus.google.com/114199965403815819875` with no `b` in it, no vanity name, or `/posts` following it.

All in all, this:

```
<a href=”https://plus.google.com/b/114199965403815819875/+GeorgiatoursEuge/posts” rel=”publisher” />
```

should become this:

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/114199965403815819875" rel="publisher" />
```

everywhere in your source code.

Comment: Also it'll probably take a while for the errors to go away since Google will continue to crawl it for a couple of weeks.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the code itself is wrong.

it should not be a href

this is how it should be within brackets:

link href="https://plus.google.com/+GeorgiatoursEuge/" rel="publisher" /

reference:

http://www.vervesearch.com/blog/how-to-implement-the-relpublisher-google-authorship-mark-up/